# Equations of two tangent lines to $y=-x^{2}+3x+10$ at an angle of $45^{\circ}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the equation of the **two** tangent lines to the Parabola $y=-x^{2}+3x+10$ that intersect the x-axis at an angle of $45^{\circ}$.

From the question I assum that the tangent line(s) has a slope of 1 and this gives me **only one** tangent line with an equation of $y=x+11$.

Is there also another tangent line that cuts the x-axis an angle of $45^{\circ}$ or Not?

Comment: Why not $-45^\circ$?

Comment: Yes, but should that not be made explicit in the question?

Comment: There are many contexts in which angles _don't_ have signs. So a $-45^\circ$ angle would also count as a $45^\circ$ angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, we have $$y=-x^2+3x+10$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-2x+3$$ Since, the tangents are inclined at an angle of $45^\circ$ with the x-axis hence their slopes are $m=\pm\tan 45^\circ=\pm 1$ as the angle is formed both in C.W. & C.C.W.

Now, equating values of slope we get $$-2x+3=\pm 1$$ $$\implies -2x+3=1\iff x=1$$ & $$\implies -2x+3=-1\iff x=2$$ Hence, substituting these values in the equation of parabola, we get corresponding y-coordinates as follows $$x=1\iff y=-1+3+10=12$$ Hence, the equation of tangent having slope $m=1$ & touching parabola at the point $(1, 12)$ is $$y-12=1(x-1)$$ $$y=x+11$$
Similarly, we get
$$x=2\iff y=-4+6+10=12$$ Hence, the equation of tangent having slope $m=-1$ & touching parabola at the point $(2, 12)$ is $$y-12=(-1)(x-2)$$ $$y=-x+14$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{equations of the tangent lines:}\ y=x+11\ ,\ y=-x+14}}$$